# How to keep polling file in a directory till it arrives in Unix

Tags: unix

I want to keep polling file till it arrives at the location for 1 hour.

My dir : `/home/stage`

File Name *(which I am looking for)*: `abc.txt`

I want to keep polling directory `/home/stage` for 1 hour but within the 1 hour if `abc.txt` file arrives then it should stop polling and should display the message `file arrived` otherwise after 1 hour it should display that `file has not arrived`.

Is there any way to achieve this in Unix?

Comment: One option would be to use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Comment: could you please give me any example of this? or how to use this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another `bash` method, not relying on trap handlers and signals, in case your larger scope already uses them for other things:

```
#!/bin/bash
interval=60
((end_time=${SECONDS}+3600))

directory=${HOME}
file=abc.txt

while ((${SECONDS} < ${end_time}))
do
  if [[ -r ${directory}/${file} ]]
  then
    echo "File has arrived."
    exit 0
  fi
  sleep ${interval}
done

echo "File did not arrive."
exit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The following script should work for you.  It would poll for the file every minute for an hour.

```
#!/bin/bash
duration=3600
interval=60
pid=$$
file="/home/stage/abc.txt"

( sleep ${duration}; { ps -p $pid 1>/dev/null && kill -HUP $pid; } ) &
trap "echo \"file has not arrived\"; kill $pid" SIGHUP

while true;
do
  [ -f ${file} ] && { echo "file arrived"; exit; }
  sleep ${interval}
done
```

Comment: Gotta remember the kill trick. There's a bunch of new things in here for me :)

Comment: It would be much cleaner to echo 'file has not arrived' and exit in the signal handler.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Couldn't agree more!  Edited above.

Comment: `while [ true ]` is a bit wonky.  In particular, it behaves exactly the same as `while [ false ]`, which both return true because they evaluate whether the string being tested is empty.  You probably meant `while true`.

Comment: -+ kill -HUP 20221
test_poll.sh: line 7: kill: (20221) - No such process
script is working fine but afte finishing successfully it is running the above commands, dont know why, have you faced the same problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an inotify script to check for `abc.txt`:

```
#!/bin/sh

timeout 1h         \
  inotifywait      \
    --quiet        \
    --event create \
    --format '%f'  \
    --monitor /home/stage |
    while read FILE; do \
      [ "$FILE" = 'abc.txt' ] && echo "File $FILE arrived." && kill $$
    done

exit 0
```

The `timeout` command quits the process after one hour. In case the file arrives, the process kills itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inotify to monitor the directory for modifications and then check to see if the file is abc.txt. The inotifywait(1) command lets you do this directly from the command line in a shell script. Check the man page for details. This is notification based.

A poll based thing would be a loop that checks to see if the file exists and if not, sleep for a period of time before checking again. That's a trivial shell script too.

Comment: inotifywait(1) command is wrong, I am not getting any manual wentry for this.  could you please give me the sytax so that I can try running that.

Comment: This command doesnt work at my end: -bash: inotifywait: command not found

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it's not installed on your machine. Install it first and then try reading the manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Here some answer with retry:

```
cur_poll_c=0
echo "current poll count= $cur_poll_c"

while (($cur_poll_c < $maxpol_count)) && (($SECONDS < $end_time))
do
  if [[ -f $s_dir/$input_file ]]
  then
    echo "File has arrived...
do some operation...
sleep 5    
    exit 0
  fi
  sleep $interval
echo "Retring for $cur_poll_c time .."
cur_poll_c=`expr $cur_poll_c+1`;
done
```