# unoconv return error when running as www-data

Tags: csv, libreoffice, unoconv

When running this from command line as `root` it works

```
unoconv -f csv $file
```

But when running it as `www-data` this error is returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 1114, in <module>
    office_environ(of)
  File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 203, in office_environ
    os.environ['PATH'] = realpath(office.basepath, 'program') + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 633, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

## update

```
echo shell_exec('echo $PATH');
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: What is the value of `www-data`'s `$PATH` and the root's `$PATH`?  Try setting `www-data`'s path before running the command.  See https://dirtyvital.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/editing-path-temporarily-or-permanently-in-unix-using-bash-shell/.

Comment: what do you mean by `www-data`'s path?

Comment: I mean set the path to something so that it is not empty.  That way the key will exist in the `os.environ` dict.  For example you could set it to `.` or a path to an empty directory.

Comment: have updated my question..

Comment: Ok, it doesn't seem to be empty.  What is `shell_exec` -- are you using PHP?  If so then please add that tag, and post the actual PHP code that contains the call.  I have not used PHP before but maybe I can help.

Comment: The call is `echo $PATH` and it outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98613/discussion-between-jim-k-and-clarkk).

Answer (score 1):

centos 7.3 with php via php-fpm 
the env in php is cleaned by php-fpm

u can use putenv to set evn["PATH"] in php code, examples

```
putenv("PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"); 
var_dump(shell_exec('unoconv -vvvv -f pdf -o 123.pdf 123.doc));
```

or u can set env use one line shell cmd

```
var_dump(shell_exec('PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin'.' unoconv -vvvv -f pdf -o 123.pdf 123.doc));
```

or u can change /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf to pass the env to php, add this line

```
clean_env = no
```

and the restart php-fpm

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP call you used (pasted from chat):

```
exec("unoconv -f csv $file")
```

My guess is that `exec()` is giving you an environment that is too limited.  To work around this, you could set up a polled directory.  The PHP script would copy files to be converted into the polled directory and wait for the files to be converted.

Then create a bash script (either running as root or a somewhat more secure user) to run in an infinite loop and check the polled directory for any incoming files.  See [How to keep polling file in a directory till it arrives in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923773/how-to-keep-polling-file-in-a-directory-till-it-arrives-in-unix) for what the bash script might look like.

When the bash script sees incoming files, it runs unoconv.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself by running libreoffice directly

```
sudo libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv --outdir $tmp_path $file
```